# Condition for $n+1$ vectors to be in general position?

Tags: linear-algebra

We say that points/vectors $v_0,\ldots v_n$ are in general position if the set $\{v_1-v_0,\ldots, v_n-v_0\}$ is linearly independent. If it is the case that any $n$ of our $n+1$ vectors are independent, does it follow that our $n+1$ vectors are in general position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(\frac12,\frac12)$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It is not a critique, nor is it a request for clarification.  It is, in fact, an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I soon thought of a similar counterexample...so I had to use the specific form of the points to prove they were in general position.

Comment: @StevenTaschuk: I would like to express my sincerest apologies for that mis-flag. But please do note that your answer does not meet certain community standards. We would much appreciate it if you could, possibly in words, express how it is that you got to this answer. In the current state of this answer, it is best as a left as a helpful comment.